# Prevent users make spam posts in Android mobile app

Tags: android, software-development

I've created app where users can posts some information in the map (like car crash and other events like that).
What will be best solution to disallow users to post fake data or advertising?

Comment: How many messages are posted per day? What proportion of all users post spam?

Comment: An app does not have active users at now. I'm searching the solution how to prevent make spam content before release.
(I think about maybe make rating system of post or something like that... )